# Getting the Active Directory username when using Windows Authentication in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, active-directory, windows-authentication

I am trying to get the windows username in my controller after using windows authentication to authenticate user on my MVC2 website.  How can I do that?  I know you can use Page.User.Identity.Name to get it from the view side?  What about the controller though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it in a Controller like so:

```
this.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name
```